# Joining Two Databases when the name of one is contained in the other

Tags: mysql, database

I have an application which has a central database which contains general information, and the information of all the companies which use my app.

So, database one is `main` and has a table `users` which, for argument's sake looks like this:

```
id   |    name   |   api_key |  databasename
 1   |  Company1 |  12345678 |  user_data_1
```

Therefore, database 2 is named `user_data_1` and would look something like this:

```
id   |    name   |   password  |  more things...
 1   |  My Name  |   abc123    |  ....
```

I know I can join these databases to fetch company and user data in one hit if I write this:

```
SELECT d2.name as username, d1.* 
FROM main.users d1, user_data_1.users d2
WHERE d1.`api_key`='12345678' AND d2.password='abc123'
```

Now, I am pretty sure the answer is no as I can't find anything that suggests I can, but is there any way to dynamically get the name of the second database from the row of the first and write this:

```
SELECT d2.name as username, d1.* 
FROM main.users d1, **(d1.databasename)**.users d2
WHERE d1.`api_key`='12345678' AND d2.password='abc123'
```

Where **(d1.databasename)** in the second SQL is an attempt to fetch the name of the second database from the row found in the first database by the `api_key` column.

Comment: You can probably do this with dynamic SQL, but your design may have a problem if you really need to do this.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't *really* need to do this, there are ways round, but it seemed like a one hit method to get two bits of data at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to dynamically get the name of the second database from the row of the first

**No**, not in pure SQL. Pure SQL does not permit symbol substitution in the naming of databases, tables, or columns.

You'll need to write a program to generate your SQL. It may be as simple as making your program generate the SQL statement

```
USE  user_data_1;
```

before issuing a bunch of ordinary queries.  In your example...

```
USE user_data_1;

SELECT d2.name as username, d1.* 
  FROM main.users d1, users d2
 WHERE d1.`api_key`='12345678' AND d2.password='abc123';
```

Notice the reference to `users` is unqualified by a database name. That means it comes from the database mentioned in the most recent `USE`.

*(You aren't really storing passwords in plain text, are you? If you are, you're making your setup vulnerable to cybercrooks.)*

Comment: Passwords are encrypted! :-)

Comment: This is good, but still requires two procedures, one to get the database to `USE` and then the joined query. It's tidy though.